# Facebook publish HTTP Error 400 : bad request

Tags: python, facebook-graph-api, urllib2, facebook-opengraph

Hey I am trying to publish a score to Facebook through python's urllib2 library.

```
import urllib2,urllib

url = "https://graph.facebook.com/USER_ID/scores"
data = {}
data['score']=SCORE
data['access_token']='APP_ACCESS_TOKEN'
data_encode = urllib.urlencode(data)
request = urllib2.Request(url, data_encode)
response = urllib2.urlopen(request)
responseAsString = response.read()
```

I am getting this error:

```
   response = urllib2.urlopen(request)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/urllib2.py", line 124, in urlopen
    return _opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/urllib2.py", line 389, in open
    response = meth(req, response)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/urllib2.py", line 502, in http_response
    'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/urllib2.py", line 427, in error
    return self._call_chain(*args)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/urllib2.py", line 361, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/urllib2.py", line 510, in http_error_default
    raise HTTPError(req.get_full_url(), code, msg, hdrs, fp)
urllib2.HTTPError: HTTP Error 400: Bad Request
```

Not sure if this is relating to Facebook's Open Graph or improper urllib2 API use.

Comment: what's in the body of the error?

Comment: Seriously though, there should be an error from Facebook's side in the body of the error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ran your code and got the same error (there is no more error in the body, would have posted that in a comment but can't yet I guess) so I googled "publish facebook scores."

I believe you'll need to grant your app permission to publish scores first, unless you've done that already. See http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/539/.

Answer (score 0):

You may have to provide user:agent as some browser. I remember getting similar error while running crawler in some website, as it detected that no browser is calling for it.

Comment: For crawling websites that maybe true – but the FB Graph API is _designed_ to be queried by server-side scripts (amongst others), so what user agent is send (or if any) should not matter here at all.