# scrape facebook likes and start getting HTTP Error 400: Bad Request

Tags: python, facebook

I was using a code to crawl Facebook likes before couple of months and **it was working fine** but now I start getting this error:

```
HTTP Error 400: Bad Request
Error for URL https://graph.facebook.com/v2.12/164637176974573_1282363268535286/likes/?limit=2000&access_token=XXXXX|XXXXX&after=MTk5MzAxOTI5MDk3MTQyNwZDZD/Page-id/likes?limit=5000&access_token= XXXXX|XXXXX: 2018-02-12 15:53:18.585000
```

What is the problem? Any idea?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Facebook publish HTTP Error 400 : bad request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11240920/facebook-publish-http-error-400-bad-request)

Comment: Most likely you are not using a page access token and you are trying to query a page

Comment: I have a valid access token, I tried it to scrape comments with it and it works but with likes i get this error:(

Comment: Have you tried to get likes from other posts? (Than that horrrrrible video, audio woke up my entire apartment..?)

Comment: Where did you get your the 'after'-value from ('MTk5MzAxOTI5MDk3MTQyNwZDZD')? Did it work at first,but then later not? Or did you try to use an old 'after'-value?

Comment: You have duplicate '?' in the url, not sure if that is how it is, if it's a typo, or the source of your problem.